# "CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected" in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting this error when I try to run one page of my ASP.NET MVC app.

> CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

This error seems to appear in this part of my Index.cshtml file for one of my pages. What I wanted to do is make sure that only one, specific user can edit, delete or see details for things in table. So, I used the method we used in class:

```
<p>
@if (User.Identity.Name == "admin.bikeshop@gmail.com")
{
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TerminID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.TerminID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TerminID })
}
</p>
```

Anyway, this error is referred to second `@Html` line of code.
So, I get the error but I don't see where should I put **","** and in Visual studio **"@"** for error line is not yellow. When I deleted that **"@"** to see what happens it moved the error to the third `@Html` line. When I deleted the **"@"** from that line as well, it did not show any mistake in Visual but the error I got in browser was now:

> CS1003: Syntax error, ';' expected

So I don't really know why it does this. My friend used the same method for his project and it works perfectly fine for him.

Comment: I think you cannot use | this symbol just like that. If you need it to be there, try to insert it into html tag (for example <span>|</span>

Comment: I am wondering about 'id = item.TerminID "? Can you show your model and how <p> is wrapped?

Comment: @JohnRonald Well, "|" was automatically created by Visual when I created class "Termin".

Comment: @Sergey "id=item.TerminID" was automatically created when I made class "Termin", I didn't add that. <p> is wrapped in <td>, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: No, for some reasons I told item is a part of foreach. Could you show the whole view with your model pls?

Comment: @JohnRonald Hey, I just deleted all "|" and my code is working for now. It seems you were right.

Comment: @Sergey Do you want me to show you while Index file for Termin class or what?

Comment: Since it is fine now , I don't need anything. As I told i just could'n understand where new { id = item.TerminID } is from but it doesn't matter now if your links are working properly.

Comment: Well the class is called Termin so for every other class that id is different. For class "Ponuda" it's "new { id = item.PonudaID}" and so on. I don't know where that's how it should be, but that's how they were created. Now I get an error when I try to create one item in Class Termin, but every other class is working normally.
From one problem to another I guess. hahaha

Answer (score 0):

remove | sign inside for loop. by this change it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
<p>
    @if (User.Identity.Name =="admin.bikeshop@gmail.com")
    {
    <div>
        <span>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TerminID })</span> |
        <span>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.TerminID })</span> |
        <span>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TerminID })</span>
    </div>
    }
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Fix Error - Compiler Error Message CS1003 Syntax error, expected
```

Remove Semicolon

---

**From**

```
@using Madrasa.Models.ViewModels;
@model TeacherVM;
```

**TO**

```
 @using Madrasa.Models.ViewModels
 @model TeacherVM
```

It's Solved in my Case .
[More details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRV0wjzsEOw)